# Convert angle brackets to HTML entities without modifying tags in PHP

Tags: php, html, dom, html-encode

There are plenty of similar question here on StackOverlow, but could not find a solution to my particular problem.

I'm facing a challenge with encoding using PHP angle brackets (<,>) to HTML entities in a string that contains HTML content. The goal is to encode only the angle brackets not 'belonging' to any tag, while leaving the HTML tags untouched. Here's an example:

```
<p> sample text with equation like b<a or text <inside> brackets </p>
```

Regex solutions won't work because of too many variations. Tried HTMLPurifier, but it strips anything resembling tags. I think I need a smart enough DOM parser and then encode all text nodes. Any suggestions?

Comment: _"I think I need a smart enough DOM parser"_ - it would certainly need to "understand" HTML, if you want it to be able to realize that `<input>` is an HTML element, and `<inside>` isn't. _"Tried HTMLPurifier, but it strips anything resembling tags."_ - it offers a wide array of configuration options, and is also "extendable" - so probably still one of your best bets, if you don't want to build your own solution from scratch.

Comment: By reading that text I see following rule: Search for a `<` and remember open position. If a `>` comes up, the tag is valid, else if another `<` comes, escape the previous one, the open position needs to be overwritten. If tag name is no HTML tag, escape it.

Comment: Perhaps I could restrict the tag set to HTML 4.01 Strict, so that anything not defined within the specifications (no custom elements) would be automatically encoded. Still need a good library for that.

Comment: Why are you doing that? It would be much easier to use markdown.

Comment: Another idea would be to allow just a set of of tags and to encode all what's within.

Comment: @Markus Zeller how would you do that? Markdown is not an option, I have to deal with pre-existing text.

Comment: I am interested in why you have such crappy data source.

Comment: Such html was initially entered via a textfield input and stored in the DB as is. Now I to deal with about 300K records and try to clean these up.